# Donation through In App Purchase (IAP)

Tags: in-app-purchase, donations

I'm working on an app. I feel like putting this app as paid version will not call attention of many user's so I was thinking to release it for free.

To earn still earn some money, I'm thinking to implement the Donation option where user can select how much he/she would like to pay (in a range of documented IAP tiers: Tier1$, Tier2$, Tier3$, ...).

Is it possible to achieve this? What about the IAP categories, in which category would this kind of payment fit (Non consumable, subscription)?

Comment: Two people seem to think this question is worth bookmarking but not upvoting... (scratches head)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also considering doing this.  I looked into it several years back; An IAP at that time had to fall into one of several well-defined categories, and donations was not one of them.

How about badges?  Gold badge costs $1, Diamond costs five, Platinum costs 30.

And people can purchase badges.

Or theme the app with a different colour background; different colours cost different amounts.

Link: 
[iPhone in app purchase for charitable donations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138860/iphone-in-app-purchase-for-charitable-donations?rq=1)